# function is undefined in elixir (mix test)

Tags: erlang, elixir, jupyter-notebook, zeromq, elixir-mix

I'm trying to install [IElixir](https://github.com/pprzetacznik/IElixir) Jupyter notebook kernel on Xubuntu 16.04. I've successfully done it before on another machine with Xubuntu 16.04.

I have the latest erlang otp 19.3 and elixir 1.4.4 (installed using kiex).

After executing `mix test` i get an error about undefined `:erlzmq_nif.context/1` function:

```
** (Mix) Could not start application ielixir: exited in: IElixir.start(:normal, [])
    ** (EXIT) an exception was raised:
        ** (UndefinedFunctionError) function :erlzmq_nif.context/1 is undefined (module :erlzmq_nif is not available)
            :erlzmq_nif.context(1)
            (ielixir) lib/ielixir.ex:13: IElixir.start/2
            (kernel) application_master.erl:273: :application_master.start_it_old/4
```

The thing is all the dependencies are succesfully installed and I am able to use `:erlzmq_nif.context/1` in `iex`:

```
iex(1)> :erlzmq_nif.context 1
{:ok, ""}
iex(2)>
```

I've copied my build of `erlzmq` to `/usr/lib/erlang/lib` so that I can use it in erlang too:

```
1> erlzmq_nif:context(3).
{ok,<<>>}
2>
```

Why is this lib not visible to elixir when using mix?

Comment: check your `elixirc_paths/1` functions in `mix.exs`. There should be a clause for :text and a default. Make sure the :test clause is pulling in the correct paths.

Comment: Do you have this library set to be dependency only for `dev`?

Comment: @StevePallen there is no `elixirrc_paths/1` function in `mix.exs`.
@PatNowak no, it's set as a general dependency, just like here: https://github.com/pprzetacznik/IElixir/blob/master/mix.exs#L28.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've not **solved** the problem, bu I've manage to get *IElixir* to work.

What I've done was replace `:erlzmq` dependency in `mix.exs` with `github: "zeromq/erlzmq"` (notice no `2` in the repo name) which might not outperform `erlzmq2` as it's not NIF based, but at least it works without problems.